# Get every item from markdown list under headings

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, typescript, markdown

Here is example markdown file

```
# Test

## First List

* Hello World
* Lorem
* foo

## Second List

- item

## Third List

+ item 1
part of item 1
+ item 2

## Not a List

bla bla bla

## Empty

## Another List

bla bla bla



bla

* ITEM

## Nested List

### Inside Nested

* foo
* bar
```

I have this code so far:

```
const markdown = await fs.promises.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'test.md'), 'utf8');
const regexp = /^#{1,6} (.*)[.\n]*[*\-+] (.*)/gm;
const result = markdown.matchAll(regexp);
console.log([...result].map(m => m.slice(1)));
```

```js
[
  [ 'First List', 'Hello World' ],
  [ 'Second List', 'item' ],
  [ 'Third List', 'item 1' ],
  [ 'Inside Nested', 'foo' ]
]
```

First issue is that it's only grabbing first item, Second is that if item is multiline it will only grab first line, and finally it doesn't include `Another List` because there text in between heading and list.

I'm pretty new to regexp and not sure if current regexp I have is even safe to use.

So basically I want to find every list in markdown file put it items in an array then look if there a heading any were above and not another list of some kind and then put that heading in a beginning of that array (all thought it's not necessary have to be in that format, could be object too, I just thought array would be simpler)

Desired result:

```js
[
  ['First List', 'Hello World', 'Lorem', 'foo'],
  ['Second List', 'item'],
  ['Third List', 'item 1\npart of item 1', 'item 2'],
  ['Another List', 'ITEM'],
  ['Inside Nested', 'foo', 'bar']
]
```

Comment: Regex isn't really good for that. You can either do a second regex to split/parse the list values. Or you can do some ghetto conditional groups hard coded in to a fixed amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
/(?<=#{1,6} (.*)\n(?:(?!#).*\n)*)(?=[+*-] (.*(?:\n(?![#+*-]).+)?))/g
```

Basically it's matching all the 0 width characters and test if there's list item (e.g. `* item`) in front of it and any title (e.g. `# Title`) before it and put both of them in separate groups. Whatever in between them doesn't matter, unless it's another title.

You can [see the test cases here](https://regex101.com/r/ULD0Tj/2)

The `matchAll` result will be

```json
[
    ["", "First List", "Hello World"],
    ["", "First List", "Lorem"],
    ["", "First List", "foo"],
    ["", "Second List", "item"],
    ["", "Third List", "item 1\npart of item 1"],
    ["", "Third List", "item 2"],
    ["", "Another List", "ITEM"],
    ["", "Inside Nested", "foo"],
    ["", "Inside Nested", "bar"]
]
```

Since you cannot make a regex that has dynamic amount matching groups, you need to group them together manually.

And here's the full example:

```js
const markdown = `
# Test

## First List

* Hello World
* Lorem
* foo

## Second List

- item

## Third List

+ item 1
part of item 1
+ item 2

## Not a List

bla bla bla

## Empty

## Another List

bla bla bla



bla

* ITEM

## Nested List

### Inside Nested

* foo
* bar
`;

const regexp = /(?<=#{1,6} (.*)\n(?:(?!#).*\n)*)(?=[+*-] (.*(?:\n(?![#+*-]).+)?))/g;
const matches = [...markdown.matchAll(regexp)];
const result = matches.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const [title, item] = cur.slice(1);
    const target = acc.find(e => e[0] === title);
    if(target) {
        target.push(item);
    } else {
        acc.push([title, item]);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```